# Access number of HTML elements in class and using number to make value of tag attribute

Tags: javascript, html, class, attributes

Does anybody have any idea how to access the number of elements in a class with javascript, and then create an attribute for another element and make it's value the number of elements? For example, I want to get the number of elements in class `navT` and use that number to make a table with `id` navTH have attribute `colspan` with the value as the number of elements in class `navT`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

```
let table = document.getElementById('navTH')
let numberOfElements = document.getElementsByClassName('navT').length
table.setAttribute('colspan', numberOfElements)
```

Comment: The [*colspan*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/tabular-data.html#attributes-common-to-td-and-th-elements) attribute applies to [*TD*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/tabular-data.html#the-td-element) an [*TH*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/tabular-data.html#the-th-element) elements, not [*Table*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/tabular-data.html#the-table-element) elements. ;-)

Comment: Totally agree, but the naming convention just applies to OP's terminology, seeking to "use that number to make a table with id navTH have attribute colspan". I'm assuming navTH is a TH element, not a table, but just to make the code apply as closely to the question as possible, I gave the variable the label `table`.